# Storing equal objects in a set

Tags: c++, c++11, set

What I'm trying to do: order elements in the `set` by `elem->value`, but still recognize that they're distinct elements based on the memory address they're pointing to.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int value;
    
    Node(int v) : value(v) {}
};

int main()
{
    Node* a = new Node(10);
    Node* b = new Node(10);
    Node* c = new Node(20);

    if (a == b) {
        cout << "a == b" << endl;
    }
    
    if (a == c) {
        cout << "a == c" << endl;
    }
    
    auto comparator = [](Node* lhs, Node* rhs) {
        return lhs->value < rhs->value;
    };

    set<Node*, decltype(comparator)> s(comparator);
    s.insert(a);
    s.insert(b);
    s.insert(c);
    
    cout << "after inserts, s.size() = " << s.size() << endl;
    
    s.erase(a);
    
    cout << "after erase, s.size() = " << s.size() << endl;
    
    delete(a);
    delete(b);
    delete(c);

    return 0;
}
```

Since `a != b`, I expect to get:

```
after inserts, s.size() = 3
after erase, s.size() = 2
```

But instead, I get:

```
after inserts, s.size() = 2
after erase, s.size() = 1
```

With `lhs->value <= rhs->value`, I get:

```
after inserts, s.size() = 3
after erase, s.size() = 3
```

With `multiset`, I get:

```
after inserts, s.size() = 3
after erase, s.size() = 1
```

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.  What is the actual thing you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the memory address for tie-break.

Example:

```
auto comparator = [](Node* lhs, Node* rhs) {
    return lhs->value < rhs->value ||
        (lhs->value == rhs->value && lhs < rhs);
};
```

Comment: Use `std::less` for comparing unrelated pointers. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less  _"...A specialization of std::less for any pointer type yields the implementation-defined strict total order, even if the built-in < operator does not..."_

Comment: @NathanOliver It looks like "unspecified", not "undefined", according to [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 5.9 Relational operators.

Comment: Yep, you need to use `std::less` instead. Which is the default comparator for `std::set`, so there’s no need to explicitly specify one; in this situation, `less` is more.

Comment: @MikeCAT unspecified, meaning that it can’t satisfy the requirements for a strict partial order.

Comment: @Sneftel when not using a custom comparator the code compiles, but doesn't work -- the objects aren't ordered by `value`. The code in the answer does work and I don't care about the order of the pointers, I just need to distinguish them from each other.

Comment: @andrey It works *for you*. The behavior is unspecified, the comparison isn't required to be consistent between evaluations, even when given the same pointers. The code could break if compiled on a different implementation or with different flags. Using `std::less` achieves the result intended by this answer, and is portable.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux by `std::less`, do you mean this: `lhs->value < rhs->value || (lhs->value == rhs->value && less<Node*>{}(lhs, rhs))`?

Comment: @andrey Yes, the comments above are recommending replacing the pointer comparison with `std::less`. But in reality, the `value` comparison is harmful and not useful. At best, the pointed objects never change and you can just compare pointers directly. At worst, a pointer `Node`'s value changes, breaking the ordering and breaking the entire `set`. So it would be best to just use `std::less` and not even use a custom comparator. Edit : I see the goal is to sort the elements by value as well. This is very strange use case, where I guess the `value` comparison is relevant, but dangerous.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux To clarify -- the danger is the same for any container whose elements are indexed by its values and when the values can be modified outside of its API, right?

Comment: @andrey Yes, this is a risk any time a key's order in the container can be changed. It is usually preferable to stick with key values. For example `std::set<Node>` and compare just the value, or `std::set<Node*>` and compare pointer values. Normally, when two objects have indistinguishable states, they should compare as equal. I don't really understand what the use case is, but from the question it seems that this answer is what you are looking for, except using `std::less` instead of comparing the pointers directly.